# addResourceHandlers and setOrder property

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am developing a web application using Spring-MVC4 and i have a strange behavior with static resources handler. when i set resource handler as below :

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
}
```

all work fine but when i set the following configuration my webapp does not handle static resource (css and js) :

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    //registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
}

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}
```

PS: myweb my Web initializer

```
public class MyWebInitializer extends
        AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {



    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { WebAppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {RootAppConfig.class};
    }
}
```

i have this behavior only with this application, in an other application just overriding addResourceHandlers or configureDefaultServletHandling methods work without setOrder 
any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made an error in my controller  i write this :

```
@RequestMapping(name = "/team/add/process", method = RequestMethod.POST)

public String excuteAddTeamForm(/*Params..*/){
 //...
}
```

I forgot to specify "RequestMapping" value (i set instead name= "/team/add/process"). This means that the "excuteAddTeamForm" is considered as the default handler method. Therefore, when browser send a GET request to the server (with GET /resources/**), this request is handled by excuteAddTeamForm because a ResourceHandlerRegistry has a lower priority than servletDispatcher.